# Opencart create children page on Information Catalogue

Tags: opencart

My question is quite simple.

I would like to know if there is any simple way for me to create a sub-page into the Catalog > Informations into the admin panel.

My point si that I need to create Some CMS pages with a parent page. I would like to have a solution that only cost time and not a buyable plugin ;)

The documentation of OpenCart is quite useless : http://docs.opencart.com/display/opencart/Information

Any idead or links?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no *simple nor costy way*. Either you can buy a *CMS extension* (IMO pricey option) or to invest your own time to implement such functionality on your own. the whole structure of information pages would have to be reworked as well as all other modules displaying information pages (information module, sitemap module, footer) to allow you to display information pages tree. Good luck!

Comment: This is what I was thinking.. Thx.